# Error "Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section" in "Hello World" app

Tags: java

I keep getting the following error code when i try to run hello world. it says internal error

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
    }
}
```

Above is the code I copied from my professor but it seems to work for everyone except me. producing the following statements which I know nothing about

```
Internal error (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException): org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.CannotLoadJpsModelException: Cannot parse file /Users/jayrobinson/IdeaProjects/Hello World/Hello World.iml: ParseError at [row,col]:[12,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.CannotLoadJpsModelException: Cannot parse file /Users/JayRobinson/IdeaProjects/Hello World/Hello World.iml: ParseError at [row,col]:[12,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:378)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:325)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:193)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.CannotLoadJpsModelException: Cannot parse file /Users/jayrobinson/IdeaProjects/Hello World/Hello World.iml: ParseError at [row,col]:[12,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.tryLoadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.lambda$loadModules$1(JpsProjectLoader.java:353)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jdom.JDOMException: ParseError at [row,col]:[12,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadUsingStaX(JDOMUtil.java:292)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.tryLoadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:76)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[12,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.SafeStAXStreamBuilder.build(SafeStAXStreamBuilder.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadUsingStaX(JDOMUtil.java:285)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: It looks like you are having a problem with your system.  That is the way Java or your IDE is installed.  1. Uninstall everything.  2. Install just the Java JDK.  Test that with the code you got from your professor, and tell us the result.  Let's first make sure you have Java correct.

Comment: Here's is a not terrible tutorial how to compile code with just the JDK, from the command line.  If you need help Googling for more info is useful.  https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/

Comment: delete the ```.iml``` file and try to run?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the Intellij project file `/Users/jayrobinson/IdeaProjects/Hello World/Hello World.iml`. There's nothing wrong with the code. My advice is to create a new intellij java project, create your Main.java class file again and try to run your new project.

Comment: Just as a side note, you should never edit the .iml file(s) as intellij maintains these files for you.